# Ranking data (descending)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've written a query which ranks products by cash sales data but does it in ascending order ie the product with the smallest sales appears first!

Do you know how I can amend the code below so it ranks the data in DESCENDING instead of ascending order?

With the Order By function, you can just put the letters DESC after Order By:

```
select 
    es.ClientProductID,
    es.ProductName,
    ash.sales * ash.Price as CashSales, 
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ash.sales * ash.Price) as RankedDataBySales 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID

where es.SubcategoryName = 'Yogurt' and ash.segmentid = 0;
```

TIA

Comment: DID you try adding the `DESC` keyword to `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: I tried Zaynul's solution below and it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
select 
    es.ClientProductID,
    es.ProductName,
    ash.sales * ash.Price as CashSales, 
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY (ash.sales * ash.Price) desc) as RankedDataBySales 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID

where es.SubcategoryName = 'Yogurt' and ash.segmentid = 0;
```

from your comment it seems you want top 10 rank sales so put below query

```
with cte as
 (
select 
        es.ClientProductID,
        es.ProductName,
        ash.sales * ash.Price as CashSales, 
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY (ash.sales * ash.Price) desc) as RankedDataBySales 
    from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash
    join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID

    where es.SubcategoryName = 'Yogurt' and ash.segmentid = 0;
) select * from cte where RankedDataBySales>=10
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you very much, Zaynul!! Woo! You've made my day better!

Comment: Hi Zaynul, do you know how I can modify the code to return the top 10 results from Yogurts (and the middle selling products) by cash sales? For the Top 10, I added this to the first line, but it just returns all data including data I hadn't requested: select Top 10 *,
 es.ClientProductID,
 es.ProductName,
 ash.sales * ash.Price as CashSales, 
 RANK() OVER(ORDER BY (ash.sales * ash.Price) DESC) as RankedDataBySales 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID

where es.SubcategoryName = 'Yogurt' and ash.segmentid = 0;

Comment: use top keyword in selection btw if it helps accept answer

Comment: @Mr2017 you use  sub query and put condition RankedDataBySales>10

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure how to do that. Would you be able to provide an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    es.ClientProductID,
    es.ProductName,
    ash.sales * ash.Price as CashSales, 
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ash.sales * ash.Price DESC) as RankedDataBySales 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID
where es.SubcategoryName = 'Yogurt' and ash.segmentid = 0;
```

Comment: just use the DESC keyword in order by argument used inside over() clouse. By default it takes order by takes ASC order.